# location.reload() behaving differently in chrome vs ff on page arrived at by POST

Tags: javascript, post, reload

For non-negotiable reasons unique to the legacy system I am doing work on, a POST query is used to switch between tabs of a particular web interface.

On occasion, I need to trigger a refresh of the current tab and would typically use js's `location.reload()` to accomplish this. However, in this context the behavior is different in Firefox vs. Chrome.

Specifically, FF resubmits the POST query that brought me to my current page, whereas Chrome does not. As a result, FF ends up where I started, and Chrome instead goes to the URL in the address bar.

Does anyone know of a cross-browser means of accomplishing what FF does by default on `location.reload()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using it with true

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work either for what I'm trying to do. It is good to know about that argument though; I didn't realize location.reload() pulled from the cache by default.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in Chrome.

Take a look at the attached bug description.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30479

Although it mentions the back button, I see the same issue using location.reload(true) if I have a form using session cookies. That is, in IE and FF it reposts and reloads OK. In Chrome it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Reload using location property:

```
window.location = window.location;
```

Comment: This does the opposite of what I'm trying to do -- making both FF and Chrome go to the current window.location rather than resubmitting the previous POST.

Comment: I see, I thought you are just trying to refresh the page. In this case you need to trigger form submission again if you need to repost the form.